# what should be jboss.bind.address should be when running jboss instance?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

One of our web projects is configured to run on `JBoss EAP 6.` In our development machine, I set

```
jboss.bind.address=192.168.XX.X (This is the IP of the machine I run JBOSS)
jboss.bind.address.management=192.168.XX.X
```

what should I have for my local development box.
I tried the following:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.YY.YY (This is the ip address of my computer when I execute `ifconfig`)
0.0.0.0
```

I tried all the above in my local box. I find that `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.YY.YY` starts without any error. But `0.0.0.0` throws following error.

I don't totally understand how this jboss.bind.address and jboss.bind.address.management are used.

This [blog](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/jboss-start-up-configuration) mentions

*You can bind the application server public interfaces to a different IP address using:
standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.0.1*.

But I don't understand what this binding means? I tried to look up in JBoss docs too. But I did not quite understand what the purpose of this address.

```
Mar 12 21:52:19 local7:2015-03-13 04: 52:19,463 INFO  [ServerService Thread Pool -- 76] [stdout] GMS: address=0.0.0.0/singleton, cluster=singleton, physical address=0.0.0.0:55200
Mar 12 21:52:19 local7:2015-03-13 04: 52:19,463 INFO  [ServerService Thread Pool -- 76] [stdout] -------------------------------------------------------------------
Mar 12 21:52:19 local7:2015-03-13 04: 52:19,466 ERROR [ServerService Thread Pool -- 76] [fail] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.singleton.global-component-registry: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.singleton.global-component-registry: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
Mar 12 21:52:19 ...chronousService.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
    Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
Mar 12 21:52:19 ...ories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:247)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.GlobalComponentRegistryService.start(GlobalComponentRegistryService.java: 57)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:86)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
        at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
Mar 12 21:52:19 ...t org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java: 886)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:657)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:646)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:549)
        at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:225)
        ... 6 more
Mar 12 21:52:19 ...cheException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java: 209)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:198)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Mar 12 21:52:19 ...nfinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:203)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: connecting to channel "null" failed
        at org.jgroups.JChannel._connect(JChannel.java:542)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:283)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:268)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:207)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to start server socket
Mar 12 21:52:19 ..._SOCK.java:308)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.down(FD.java: 290)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.down(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:84)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.down(NAKACK.java:569)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST2.down(UNICAST2.java:544)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.down(STABLE.java:329)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.down(GMS.java:931)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:351)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:351)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.down(FRAG2.java:147)
Mar 12 21:52:19 ...org.jgroups.protocols.RSVP.down(RSVP.java:143)
        at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.down(ProtocolStack.java: 1030)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.down(JChannel.java:722)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel._connect(JChannel.java:536)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: bind_addr /0.0.0.0 is not a valid interface: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.jgroups.util.Util.createServerSocket(Util.java:3404)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.startServerSocket(FD_SOCK.java:568)
        at org.jgroups.prot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

When you bind to 0.0.0.0 you are binding to all IP addresses on the host. If there is something else already bound to one of the ports that JBoss is using on any of the IP addresses you will see this error.

JBoss binds to ports so that any connections to the port are directed to JBoss. If there is another process already listening to the port then the port is locked to that other process and JBoss cannot bind it.

The Management IP address and ports are used to manage JBoss configuration whereas the jboss.bind.address is for end-user access. The management address would normally be set to an internal IP address that may be on a different interface in a production environment (e.g. a back-end interface).

The error above is related to jgroups management ports...

```
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
```

Check that no other process on your machine already has one of these ports open (another JBoss instance perhaps?)

You can also start jboss with an offset, so all ports are increased by the offset you specify. For example if you start jboss with

```
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
```

then port 8080 becomes 8180 and so on. This may prevent port conflicts. Or just use a specific (otherwise unused) ip address for management - it really depends on your environment.

Comment: can you please explain where these ports are used by JBOSS? I mean what does 'bind' mean here?